# how to define a state with array and how to use setState() method for it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[i am making an API based project and I am getting an array(an array containing array), I want to use the entire array tell me how to define a state with array and how to use setState() method for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfmX0.jpg)

Comment: see the pic attach to it

Comment: Don't just post a link to a picture. Use `code block` to post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to set the initial state. An example of doing this would look something like:

```
class AvailabilityStatus extends React.Component {

   constructor() {
   super();

   this.state = {
    *statusArray: []
  }
}

   componentDidMount(){
     **axios.get("LinkToYourData").then((response)=>{
        ***this.setState(()=>{
           return {
             statusArray: response.data
           }
        })
   })
}

}
```

*So that's where you set the initial state of the application.

** I'm assuming that you will be using some kind of ajax call to grab your data, in 
 this example, I use axios.

***This is how you go about setting the state that you declared initially.

From the React docs:

**Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.**

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state for more info.